# Wrong print in C program

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int x[] = {2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 9};
  int j, i, s;
  for (i=0; i<6; i++){
    if (x[i] % 2 == 1){
      break;
    }
  }

  printf("%d", i);
  for (j=5; j>1; j--){
    x[j+1] = x[j];
  }
  printf("%d", i);

  return 0;
}
```

First `printf` prints 1 while the other `printf` prints 9 . And I haven't changed `i` in the meantime as you can see. Why does it print 9?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You refer to `x[j+1]` when `j` is `5`. That's outside the bounds of the array.

The behaviour of your code is therefore *undefined*. (Interestingly, the behaviour of your code is consistent with `x[6]` being equivalent to `j`, and `x[7]` being `i` and a particular sequencing in the assignment, but **don't** rely on any of that.)

Comment: Correct me if im wrong ; So any kind of undefined behaviour in c can cause unexplained changes in program ?

Comment: @JamesGroon Well, I mean technically ub being invoked would be the explanation, but yes.